# How does std::array bounds checking work?

Tags: c++

I'm a little bit confused with std::array bounds checking.

Here's the code:

```
    const size_t studentResponses = 10; 
    const size_t surveyBound = 6;

    std::array<unsigned int, studentResponses> students{ 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 2, 2 };
    std::array<unsigned int, surveyBound> survey{}; //initializes it to '0'

    for (size_t answer = 0; answer < students.size(); ++answer) {
        ++survey[students[answer]];
    }

    std::cout << "Rating" << std::setw(12) << "Frequency" << std::endl;
    
    for (size_t rating = 1; rating < survey.size(); ++rating) {
        std::cout << std::setw(6) << rating << std::setw(12) << survey[rating] << std::endl;
    }
```

Output:

```
Rating   Frequency
 1           1
 2           2
 3           1
 4           2
 5           4
```

I've never used an array as a counter for another array. From what I understand by reading the book is that the value at 'n' element of `students` will become the value of survey's elemen, but when the output is displayed, that's where my confusion is.

1. How is the array, `survey`, keeping a count of how many times of the value at of element in students is counted?
2. Since the array `survey` is initialized to 6, how can it get the 10 values from `students`?

My prof didn't really explain and just read it off a PowerPoint, so I'm trying to learn and understand it myself.

Comment: The code above implements an algorithm called *counting sort*. You may find it helpful to look that up independently to get a better sense of how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is the array, `survey`, keeping a count of how many times of each element in students is counted?

By using this statement:

```
++survey[students[answer]];
```

Note that the `students` array must contain only values between 0 and 5 (inclusive). Then the value of `students[answer]` is used as an index into `survey`. The value at that index is then incremented.

> Since the array survey is initialized to 6, how can it get the 10 values from students?

There are not 10, but only 6 positions in `survey`. Instead, the *sum* of all the values in `survey` will be equal to 10.

Comment: AHHHH. This makes a lot of sense now. Thank you very much kind sir!

Comment: No that was a very thorough answer. One more quick question though, it's only inclusive because it's not initialized? I'm assuming initialization of it would render this code useless.

I'm more of a student who needs to practice the code, visualize the code and then understand.

Comment: No, `survey` *is* initialized. That's what the `{}` is for (in fact, if it's not initialized, the `++` is broken). The 0 to 5 inclusive is because `survey` only has 6 elements. If you use any other index, the program is broken (it has undefined behavior).

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, you answered what I meant haha.